# Basic problem about local ring and dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Probably this is just a misunderstanding, but it's making me waste a lot of my time. I'm studying commutative algebra through Kemper's book. There is the following statement in chapter 12 (dimension theory).

[image]

But if we suppose $\mathfrak{q}\subsetneq\mathfrak{m}$, then we get the chain of prime ideals $\{0\}/\mathfrak{q}\subsetneq\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{q}$ in $R/\mathfrak{q}$, therefore $\dim(R/\mathfrak{q})=1$. This is so straightforward so I can't get the error, what is wrong with this reasoning?

Thanks for helping.

PS: I already know that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{q}=nil(R/\mathfrak{q})$, but this didn't help.

Comment: $\{0\}/\mathfrak q$ has no  meaning; quotients $I/J$ can be written only for ideals with $J\subseteq I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathfrak{q}$ is not assumed prime, so that $R/\mathfrak{q}$ is not a domain. In fact, $\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}} = \mathfrak{m}$ implies that the intersection of all prime ideals containing $\mathfrak{q}$ is $\mathfrak{m}$. This can only happen if $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{q}$; $\mathfrak{q}$ included.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{q}$ is not prime then $\{0\}/\mathfrak{q}$ is not a proper ideal or it's not even an ideal?

Comment: @Integral I assume you mean $\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q}$ -- the $0$ in $R/\mathfrak{q}$ -- in which case, it is an ideal. Just not a prime ideal.

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry, I guess I'm used to work only with integral domains.

Comment: @Integral Domains are pretty nice. And the whole introduction to ring theory covered in most modern algebra textbooks is based on the theory of domains. So it is not an uncommon mistake.